# How to grep a continuous stream, with paging

Tags: linux, bash, grep, less

I posted this to Superuser but got no takers: https://superuser.com/questions/832578/how-to-grep-a-continuous-stream-with-paging

I want to take a log file and filter out some irrelevant log entries, like ones at the INFO level. The above Stack Overflow answer got me part of the way:

```
$ tail -f php_error_log | grep -v INFO
```

The next piece I want is to have paging in this stream, such as with less. less +F works on continuous streams but I can't apply that to grep. How can I accomplish this?

---

Since posting that question I worked on it and discovered that `less` is waiting for the EOF to appear, and hangs until it receives it ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139295/67113)). This explains why trying to follow a pipe is not working. I hacked up a short script to do what I want, inelegantly:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -f /data/tmp/test.txt | grep --line-buffered foo > /data/tmp/foo &
pid=$!
echo $pid
sleep 1
less +F /data/tmp/foo
kill $pid
rm /data/tmp/foo
```

I'm convinced it's possible to do this more elegantly, perhaps with a temp file that is automatically cleaned up without direct interaction.

Comment: How about piping to  "less -B" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
grep -V INFO php_error_log | less +F
```

Or, you can run `multitail php_error_log`, then once multitail starts, press `e` and follow the prompts to add a regular expression to filter on.  For continuous monitoring of one or more log files over time, multitail is a good solution.

Comment: You can't pipe `grep` to `less +F` to get the desired behavior because `less +F` hangs waiting for the `EOF` before it will display any data.

Comment: +1 for the part about multitail and the e command.

Comment: I must've missed the recommendation for `multitail` originally. I just came back to this question and tried it, and it works.